# Apple app store: submit app for review but don't publish it?

Tags: ios, app-store

Can I submit my app to the app store for review, but not publish it yet even once it's approved?

I'm trying to do everything I can towards the launch, to make sure we don't run into any serious delays due to Apple's app store policies.

This is the first time I'm doing it, and there's nothing in my app that I believe may cause it to be rejected. I'm just trying to make the process as painless as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Far easier, submit with "Hold for Developer Release". After it gets approved you can go to iTunes Connect and release whenever you want.
During "ready to upload binary" process you get this choice:

[image: itunes connect screencap]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Art/up_version_release_control_2x.png))</sub>

Edit: Apple changed iTunes Connect and updated their documentation. Concept is the same but UI has changed, and the earlier documentation link is broken. (Thanks for not forwarding any old URL's, Apple!) Now you can find documentation at (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH14-SW2)

and the Release This Version button is at upper right like this:

[image: itunes connect screecap]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Art/PendingDevRelease_2x.png))</sub>

Comment: Outdated UI. This is now done through App Store Connect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can,  when you create your app in iTunesConnect, it ask you ,

Select the availability date and price tier for your app.

[image]

Comment: if I put a date which is for example two months in the future, would they still put my app in the regular line, or push it backwards?

Comment: Yes it put your app regular line, not backwards

Answer (score 0):

You can submit an app for review without automatically publishing it after a successful review by selecting that option before submission.

The "Version Release" section at the bottom of the "Prepare for Submission" page reads,

> This app version can be automatically released right after it has been approved by App Review. You can also manually release it at a later date on the App Store Connect website or in App Store Connect for iOS.

There are three options for the release schedule:

> - Manually release this version
> - Automatically release this version
> - Automatically release this version after App Review, no earlier than <date and time entry form>

The [App Store Connect Help](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect) page documents this in more detail.