# Can we delay the First App Publish on Production after it is Successfully Reviewed by Google Playstore?

Tags: android, publish

**For Android app**, Can I submit my app to the app store for review, but **not publish it yet on Production (Go-Live) even once it's approved**?
It is the First release on playstore.

I am clear about how it works for the Appstore as the same question is [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22935041/apple-app-store-submit-app-for-review-but-dont-publish-it),  But not for Playstore as I could not find any clear answers around.

Basically, I want to have the App reviewed by Google, and then once they accept, I want to publish it through manual process on a Specific Date in future in about 2 months. Is that possible to select a far off future date?
Ofcourse no changes will be done to the build that is ready for Production Release on Playstore.

**P.S.** I have already used AppCenter to roll out Test Releases to internal group of users to get the initial feedback. So no I am ready to release on Android. however, I need to plan this well with some timelines that having some Governance aspects to handle so I need to know this.

Comment: Yes, you can. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859654?hl=en

Comment: @MaximM : This link tells about publishing app changes, not about Publishing the app for the first time. Changes are at a later stage ofcourse

Comment: to be bulletproof sure, you could release it to beta track with access by email address(you can add only your email, so only you will be able to see it in Play Store), after the review rollout from beta to release takes only a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Yep the google play console having an option of manual publishing after review.

In the drawer, go to Publishing overview -> Turn on managed publishing -> Check: Managed publishing on

I hope this helps

Comment: I think we cannot do Manage Publishing on/off when we do not have the App on playstore yet.
Got this line below from https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859654?hl=en
"Your app must already be available to use managed publishing. You can’t use it when publishing an app for the first time".